# Como criar um sistema de upload que cria e modifica o html

Tags: html, upload, pdf

Galera estou tentando criar uma biblioteca online, achei uma solução open-source que você coloca o pdf na pasta e muda o endereço no index.html. Quando você fizer isso ele vai criar um visualizador do pdf.
Tem algum jeito de eu criar um arquvio (php,html, qualquer um) que quando eu enviar um pdf ele crie outra pasta e modifique o endereço do arquivo
segue abaixo o codigo
A linha que quero alterar é 52 ou seja a ultima

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>Demo of pdfListView</title>

    <style>
        .page-container {
          margin: 10px auto;
        }

        .page-view canvas {
          box-shadow: black 0px 0px 10px;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- File from the PDF.JS Library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="external/compatibility.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="external/pdf.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">PDFJS.workerSrc = 'external/pdf.worker.js';</script>

    <!-- Leave out the following two files if you don't need a textLayer -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/TextLayer.css">
    <script src="src/TextLayerBuilder.js"></script>

    <!-- Leave out the following two files if you don't need an annotations layer -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/AnnotationsLayer.css">
    <script src="src/AnnotationsLayerBuilder.js"></script>

    <!-- Core pdfListView file -->
    <script src="src/PdfListView.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main" style="position: absolute; top:0px; bottom:0px; left: 0; right: 0; overflow:scroll">
    <!-- The pageContainers go here !-->
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    window.pdfListView = new PDFListView(
        document.getElementById("main"),
        {
            // Comment out the next line to get a listView without textLayer.
            textLayerBuilder: TextLayerBuilder,
            annotationsLayerBuilder: AnnotationsLayerBuilder,
            logLevel: PDFListView.Logger.DEBUG
        }
    );
    pdfListView.loadPdf("http://playofthegame.me/ebooks/A_HIST%c3%93RIA_SECRETA_DA_MA%c3%87ONARIA_E_ORDEM_ROSACRUZ_-_por_Jakim_Booz.pdf");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Leonardo, eu fiquei bem confuso porém interessado na sua pergunta, poderia explicar melhor ou dar um exemplo pratico ?

Comment: tipo assim o youtube quando tu envia um video ele cria uma pagina pro video. eu queria fazer tipo isso. so que no lugar no video é o pdf.